# Discord Bot Auto-Send Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So this is my first time coding in DiscordJS (or coding in general) and I need some help to make a bot automatically send a message in a specific channel. Could I have some help please? Thanks!

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("LemonBot is online!");
});

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const guildId = "739855462274695188";
const channelId = "739875350594584707";
const message = "!d bump"

client.login(my discord bot token)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Please show any amount of research you've done. Have you tried the documentation or discord.js guide?

Comment: @Jakye const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();



client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("LemonBot is online!");
});

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const guildId = "739855462274695188";
const channelId = "739875350594584707";
const message = "!d bump"

client.login(my discord bot token)

Comment: Edit your question and include the code there (where it can be formatted) instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online!`);

    // Getting the channel from client.channels Collection.
    const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("739875350594584707");
    // Checking if the channel exists.
    if (!Channel) return console.error("Couldn't find the channel.");
    // Sending "!d bump" to the channel.
    Channel.send("!d bump").catch(e => console.log(e));
});

client.login(process.env.DISORD_AUTH_TOKEN)
```